# Javascript image and text arrays formatting

Tags: javascript

For my website, I'm creating an array that randomly displays an image and associated text each time. I've gotten the array to work, but the first line of text starts on the bottom right corner or the image. How do I get the image to flush left and the text to start on the top with the image?

```js
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "<em>Adrian's online program is totally unique and his approach is founded on the principle that your career should really just be another way to express yourself. I am deeply grateful to have found a more fitting career in brand management and I hope to start a business down the road.</em><br>Matt, San Francisco";
r_text[1] = "<em>I can tell you that after 3+ months using this career pathfinding program that my career outlook has never been better! I am currently going through a complete career change that I would have never dreamed about before I started this program. </em><br>Conrad, San Francisco";
var random_img = new Array();
random_img[0] = '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1">';
random_img[1] = '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2">';
var total_testimonials = 2;
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_testimonials));
document.write(random_img[random_number]);
document.write(r_text[random_number]);
```

Comment: Do you mean like CSS’s `float:left;`?

Comment: This really isn't a JavaScript question; it's about HTML and CSS. Please rewrite your question to focus on those issues.

Comment: `document.write` and `new Array` are both very bad practices in JavaScript. Consider using `document.createElement` (plus appending it to the DOM) and simply `var foo = []`.

Comment: Are we sure?  Please clarify.  Does the image display at all? If so float:left with some sort of span etc might be good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), it's used in very specific cases and very rarely. If you want to render some HTML content you should use many of other DOM manipulation methods. In my example I will search for necessary container elements with [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and set their inner HTML content with [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property.

Then you should consider adding initial HTML structure for your testimonial text and image, into which you will append random content.

Finally, when content is in DOM you might want to style it with CSS. In your case you want to make image [float to the left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float), this will make text overflow it from the right.

If you fix above issues your code might start looking something like this:

```js
var r_text = [
    "<em>Adrian's online program is totally unique and his approach is founded on the principle that your career should really just be another way to express yourself. I am deeply grateful to have found a more fitting career in brand management and I hope to start a business down the road.</em><br>Matt, San Francisco",
    "<em>I can tell you that after 3+ months using this career pathfinding program that my career outlook has never been better! I am currently going through a complete career change that I would have never dreamed about before I started this program. </em><br>Conrad, San Francisco"];

var random_img = [
    '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1">',
    '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2">'
];

var total_testimonials = r_text.length;
var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * total_testimonials));

document.querySelector('.container .image').innerHTML = random_img[random_number];
document.querySelector('.container .testimonial').innerHTML = r_text[random_number];
```

```css
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
.container .image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="testimonial"></div>
</div>
```